# How could I brighten the dark texture colours without altering the light ones?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-painting, color

[image]

I want to brighten those really dark areas while retaining detail in the lighter ones.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the *Color > RGB Curves* node. Tweak the *C* curve if you want to alter the values only, not the colors. If you want to brighten the dark areas and keep the lighter ones as they are, it should give a curve like this one:

[image]